# Как заставить Hibernate игнорировать поле в Entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

Добрый день. Есть hibernate Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "photos")
public class Photo {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String linkLocation;
    private byte[] data;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "photo")
    private Customer customer;
```

Нужно, что бы поле байтов не входило в базу данных.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте аннотацию `@Transient`. Она будет означать, что поле не будет персистентным, т.е. не будет сохраняться в БД. И соответственно не будет заполняться значением при получении объекта из БД.

```
@Transient
private String name;

public String getName() {
     return name;
}
private void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name; 
}
```

Comment: Только гет метод? я все 3 отмечал) Это неправильно?

Comment: @НиколайЕгоров, можно только само поле пометить аннотацией, тогда геттер и сеттер можно писать как обычно)

Comment: Я делал так: Trannsient field, Traensient get, Transient set. Только что сделал Transient get - колонка в БД есть...Попробовал просто Transient field - тоже самое....

Comment: Все...Заработало. Пометил только поле и работает, хотя вроде, так пробовал раньше) Спасибо, в любом случае